# How to count the most frequent CloseReasonTypes per posts in the dataexplorer?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-server-2014, dataexplorer

I started to compose [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/193616/highest-flag-close-votes-per-questions-with-more-control-than-in-the-flag-queue?Limit=38369) and I find it's difficult to see why the question should be closed.

```
select
   TOP ##Limit:int?38369## -- The maximum value the hardware can handle.
   Posts.Id as [Post Link], -- Question title.
   Count(PendingFlags.PostId) as [Number of pending flags], -- Number of pending flags per questions.
   Posts.OwnerUserId as [User Link], -- Let click on the colum to see if the same user ask off-topic questions often.
   Reputation as [User Reputation], -- Interesting to see that such questions are sometimes asked by high rep users.
   Posts.Score as [Votes], -- Interesting to see that some questions have more than 100 upvotes.
   Posts.AnswerCount as [Number of Answers], -- I thought we shouldn't answer on off-  topic post.
   Posts.FavoriteCount as [Number of Stars], -- Some questions seems to be very helpfull :) .
   Posts.CreationDate as [Asked on], -- The older is the question, the more is the chance that flags on them can't get reviewed.
   Posts.LastActivityDate as [last activity], -- Similar effect as with Posts.CreationDate.
   Posts.LastEditDate as [modified on],
   Posts.ViewCount
from posts
   LEFT OUTER JOIN Users on Users.id = posts.OwnerUserId
   INNER JOIN PendingFlags on PendingFlags.PostId = Posts.Id
where ClosedDate IS NULL -- The question is not closed.
group by Posts.id, Posts.OwnerUserId, Reputation, Posts.Score, Posts.FavoriteCount, Posts.AnswerCount, Posts.CreationDate, Posts.LastActivityDate, Posts.LastEditDate, Posts.ViewCount
order by Count(PendingFlags.PostId) desc; -- Questions with more flags have more chance to get them handled, and the higher is the probabilty that the question is off-topic (since several users already reviewed the question).
```

Given that their are several flags per questions, I can't use a simple table to show the flag the reason used for each flag, but I think it should be relevant to sho the most common value of CloseReasonTypes.Id for each post : this lead me to two problems :

- **First** : After looking at [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/179779/pending-close-flags-by-close-reason), I  should *JOIN CloseReasonTypes* to *PendingFlags* to show the reason names instead of their numbers. Since there are no common field between *Posts* and *PendingFlags*, but as I'm using`from posts`as the base for joining tables, I have no clue on how to do this *JOIN*.
- **Secound** : I have no idea to select the most common used close reason on each line. While several question seems to have discussed of similar case, I can't use their answers as they ask on how to find the most common value on a whole table resulting in a table with a single column and a single line, whereas I need to do this for the count of flags on each posts.

Answer (score 1):

While not exactly what you are looking for, I believe this [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/193721/question-close-flag-count) will provide you with a good start.

```
select
    PostId as [Post Link], 
    duplicate = sum(case when closereasontypeid = 101 then 1 else 0 end), 
    offtopic = sum(case when closereasontypeid = 102 then 1 else 0 end),
    unclear = sum(case when closereasontypeid = 103 then 1 else 0 end),
    toobroad = sum(case when closereasontypeid = 104 then 1 else 0 end),
    opinion = sum(case when closereasontypeid = 105 then 1 else 0 end),
    ot_superuser = sum(case when CloseAsOffTopicReasonTypeId = 4 then 1 else 0 end),
    ot_findexternal = sum(case when CloseAsOffTopicReasonTypeId = 8 then 1 else 0 end),
    ot_serverfault = sum(case when CloseAsOffTopicReasonTypeId = 7 then 1 else 0 end),
    ot_lackinfo = sum(case when CloseAsOffTopicReasonTypeId = 12 then 1 else 0 end),
    ot_typo = sum(case when CloseAsOffTopicReasonTypeId = 11 then 1 else 0 end)
from pendingflags
where 
    flagtypeid in (13,14)   -- Close flags
    and creationdate > '2014-04-15'
group by PostId
```

This is only looking at closed posts since April 15th of this year, and returns about 23,500 records.

I believe that the data explorer does NOT contain posts there were deleted, thus those aren't included in the results.

This will need modifications if/when new close reasons are added or removed.

Comment: That's a good start, but that's not that I'm looking for :) ... So upvoted but not accepted. It don't resolve my first nor the second problem at all *(I know I could do this, but I already have others rows : It don't tell the syntax to select the most common result)*.